# How to get values from an array in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a 3 level category. I need to gain businesses on level 3 category.

I write this code:

```
$main_cat = Category::where(['slug' => $url])->first();
$lev_cat2 = Category::where(['parent_id' => $main_cat->id, 'status' => '1'])->get();
 foreach ($lev_cat2 as $subCategory) {
            $cat_ids_lv2[] = $subCategory->id . ',';
        }
 foreach ($lev_cat2 as $subCat) {
            $lev_cat3[] = Category::where(['parent_id' => $subCat->id, 'status' => '1'])->pluck('id')->toArray();
        }

dd($lev_cat3);
```

Then I got this array which is correct:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    0 => 145
    1 => 146
    2 => 147
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    0 => 148
    1 => 149
    2 => 150
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    0 => 151
    1 => 152
    2 => 153
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    0 => 154
    1 => 155
    2 => 156
  ]
  4 => []
]
```

now I dont know how can I get values like 145,146,147,148,149,... to pass theme to

```
Business::where(['category_id'=> [145,146,147,148,...]]->get();
```

of course dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use laravel collection helpers :

```
Business::whereIn('category_id', collect($lev_cat3)->flatten()->all())->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP 5.5.0 there is a built-in function [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) which does exactly this.

You can use it to Converting php array of arrays into single array then use it like this

```
$category_ids = array_column($lev_cat3);

Business::where(['category_id'=> $category_ids]]->get();
```